# Animate function with setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please, check this code I tried mostly things for animate this fiddle. 
I would like to add a `move` class this class animate with `margin-left: 25%`.

https://jsfiddle.net/o00nu4w8/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to remove the class immediately after adding it thus causing the animation not to appear when you do this

```
setInterval(function() {
      lis[c].classList.add('move');
      c++;
      lis[c-1].classList.remove('move')
      if (c === lis.length) {
        c = 0;
      }
}, 3500)
```

however if you do this

```
setInterval(function() {
      if(lis[c-1]) lis[c-1].classList.remove('move')
      lis[c].classList.add('move');
      c++;
      if (c === lis.length) {
        c = 0;
      }
}, 3500)
```

It will wait until the next interval to remove the 'move' class, allowing you to see it animate in and out

Answer (score 0):

You can make this even simpler. Problem is removing of class, too early, but you can remove class *at the end of all animations*, for all elements, and start over:

```
let lis = document.querySelectorAll('li')
let c = 0;

setInterval(function() {
      lis[c].classList.add('move');
      c++;

      if (c === lis.length) {
      lis.forEach(function(el) {
      el.classList.remove('move');
      });
        c = 0;
      }
}, 3500)
```

Demo:

```js
let lis = document.querySelectorAll('li')
let c = 0;

setInterval(function() {
      lis[c].classList.add('move');
      c++;
    
  
      if (c === lis.length) {
      lis.forEach(function(el) {
      el.classList.remove('move');
      });
       c = 0;
      }
}, 3500)
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.slideshow {
   width: 350px;
   height: 200px;
   overflow: hidden;
   border: 3px solid #F2F2F2;
}

.slideshow ul {
    /* 4 images donc 4 x 100% */
   width: 400%;
   height: 200px;
   padding:0; margin:0;
   list-style: none;
   transition: 2s;
}
.slideshow li {
   float: left;
   width: 25%;
   height: 200px;
   transition: .5s;
}
.move {
  margin-left: -25%;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
 <ul>
  <li class='red'></li>
  <li class='green'></li>
  <li class='yellow'></li>
  <li class='blue'></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```